# how to migrate windows service to appfabric?

Tags: windows-services, appfabric

I have an existing windows service that connects to the database and do updates periodically.

1. In what project type I have to convert my logic so that it can be deployed to app fabric?
2. What will be good strategies to call an sp using multiple threads parallel in appfabric?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was having a windows service and having couple of things like calculating statistics from data for view (reduce complex operations at query time ), image processing and email system.

I got a very good solution video which is describing how to do that using [Workflow services as a Batch Job](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-Services-as-a-Batch-Job)  by Rob Jacobs

Answer (score 0):

Probably to late to help you, but maybe this can help somebody else. I have written a blog post about converting a windows service to a WCF service. There are good reasons to do this and it is not that hard. See http://www.peterdol.nl/blog/convert-windows-services-to-long-running-appfabric-services/.